# Understanding Parametric UV's?

Tags: mathematics

I've watched a video on Parametric UV's but I cannot understand how to calculate, the Parametric UV's on a flat surface or a sphere.  Should I perceive Parametric UV's the same way as a UV map, which is between 0-1 ?

Comment: Might want to link to that video.

Comment: [There are many ways to make parametric UVs for a sphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections). Which one you use will depend on the specific needs for your case.

Comment: I understand there are many ways to make a parametric UV for a sphere, but suppose I want the top of the sphere to ignore anything that physically hits the sphere but it is based on the parametric UV's, it is based on a 0-1 top to bottom ?

Comment: It depends on how you chose so unwrap that sphere. We don't know how the parametrization was set up for the specific sphere you're using. Can you give us any information about the parametrization your sphere uses?